# How can I animate like open book in iBook?

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, xcode4, ibooks

I want to click image and open like when we click on book in bookshelf in iBook. Just simple flip , not to curl.Animate like we open hard-cover book :)

Could you guide me what call is that ?? or Could you guide me how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Apple example https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ViewTransitions/Introduction/Intro.html

It requires ios5 though.

But example basically uses UIView method

```
transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:
```

that is available in ios4. Here is a link for it: [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionWithView%3aduration%3aoptions%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a)

Comment: Thank.But it's not what I want. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @crazyoxygen, Did you find solution for this? I am also into the same problem. Let me know if you got the solution.

Comment: I find some tutorial couple of months ago.Not sure where it is.But it use CoreAnimation to render it. I will ask my partner when he come to office. :)